# I accidentally deleted django_admin_log and now i can not use the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I get this error

> "ProgrammingError at /admin/
>   relation "django_admin_log" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_ad..."

`django_admin_log` table does not exist in the database. Does anyone know how I can create it? I am not worried about deleting the data for my app.

when i try './manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001' or './manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001'

i get 
"

### BEGIN;

### -- Create model LogEntry

CREATE TABLE "django_admin_log" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "action_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "object_id" text NULL, "object_repr" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "action_flag" smallint NOT NULL CHECK ("action_flag" >= 0), "change_message" text NOT NULL, "content_type_id" integer NULL, "user_id" integer NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_content_type_id_c4bce8eb_fk_django_content_type_id" FOREIGN KEY ("content_type_id") REFERENCES "django_content_type" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "django_admin_log_417f1b1c" ON "django_admin_log" ("content_type_id");
CREATE INDEX "django_admin_log_e8701ad4" ON "django_admin_log" ("user_id");
COMMIT;"

but i still get the same error? i use postgresql if anyone cares.

Answer (score 3):

experienced the same issue, the best way is to copy the CREATE TABLE log, login to your database ./manage.py dbshell and Paste the content over there without adding the last line (COMMIT ) it will solve the problem and manually create the table for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the table from scratch for Django 1.7 > :

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001
```

Answer (score 0):

After `./manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001`, please run `python manage.py migrate`.